# CSS Background Overloads

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand someone's CSS [>> HERE <<](http://wellstyled.com/files/css-nopreload-rollovers/example2.html#).

Basically, he has defined his `background` element with this syntax:

```
background: url( 'bars.gif' ) 0 -50px no-repeat;
```

My image is a different size than his, so I am trying to adjust my code to fit my image. However, the w3schools info on [CSS Background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) shows that this format should be used:

```
background: #ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;
```

Where is the overload info for `background` located?

Comment: What do you mean by overload info?

Comment: Like as in Object Oriented programming where something can be supplied different parameters. The example the website uses contains a different set of parameters than what the CSS standard calls for. Where do I find the optional parameters so I can understand what values he is specifying in his example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

Short answer: **The order is irrelevant to the final product.**

Background is shorthand for five different properties.

- background-color (# followed by digits or a named color)
- background-image (url('url goes here'))
- background-repeat (repeat, repeat-x, ...)
- background-attachment (fixed, scroll)
- background-position (location, percent, or pixels)

Notice that each option contains a unique formatting. This allows the renderer to understand the declaration without relying on a specific order. Also, any parameters unspecified are set to the default.

W3schools suggests a format to reduce the cognitive load on developers (which obviously didn't work in this case). I would suggest that you stick with W3's suggestion to hopefully avoid this confusion in the future.

Comment: Or if you tend to develop with Firebug as a constant companion (as I do), you could use the order they reformat to.